# Label text value in treeview node

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview with several nodes. I have a lable which has the value like

```
Label1.Text = LoginName1.Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

I want to give this value to the treeview node. How can I do that?

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as:

```
treeNode1.text = Label1.Text
```

Comment: There is no treenode1. Even if i consider it as treeview1 then there is no .Text property

Comment: well, you didn't write it is asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using the code as,

```
TreeView1.Nodes[0].Text = Label1.Text;
```